# linux apache2.4.35 php7.2 curl does not execute in text result but in html does

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have been build production Webserver but i stuck in:
linux apache2.4.35 php7.2 curl does not execute in text result but in html does.
I just run this code file name test.php:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com:port/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

browser output should be:

```
INVALID PARAMETER
```

not :

```
blank (empty page)
```

my link test : http://example.com/test.php (offline)

environment:
- Centos 7
- apache2.4.35
- PHP7.2.11
- curl7.61.1 enable (phpinfo) 
I was try run from php cli work well and from XAMPP for linux with any browser run well too (in the same environment). 
I found difference in phpinfo (additional dotini files) there is "php-zts" but in cli just "php". Can anyone help ?, may be there are missing configs in httpd.conf or in php.ini. I appreciate to hear your advice, thanks -alfin-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like SELinux issue, please try to run

```
setenforce 0
```

from your root console. This will temporary disable SELinux. You will be able to configure property it later to enable network activity for web server.

If this temp fix worked, you can enable network access using

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect
```

and enable SELinux again:

```
setenforce 1
```

Comment: Yess great.. i spent many time, and work well now, Thanks a lot Alexander Gerasimov

Comment: In this case you can run: 

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect && setenforce 1`

Comment: when i run setsebool... get notice: `libsepol.expand_filename_trans: Conflicting name-based type_transition staff_gkeyringd_t gnome_home_t:dir "keyrings":  data_home_t vs gkeyringd_gnome_home_t
libsepol.expand_module: Error during expand
libsemanage.semanage_expand_sandbox: Expand module failed`. Searching google it doesnt found any information specific. I dont know about SELinux at all

Comment: ok solve now.. there is conflict module, done with disable module gnome. CASE CLOSE

Comment: spent a whole day on this, this answer saved me 
thank you so much @AlexanderGerasimov